# Background color change shown in debugger, but not on screen

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I am trying to change the `background color` of an element. The debugger in Chrome tells me I have done so, but the color does not show up on screen.

This particular element has `!important` for the `background color`.

If I try to do the same thing on an element without `!important` it works.

It does not seem to matter if I do the changes from javascript only, jQuery or the debugger.

I am quite a bit confused at the moment, but perhaps I can guess rather safely assume that there is a bug in either Chrome or its debugger, or?

Maybe it matters that this is in a bookmarklet. (And this prevents me at the moment to even test it in Firefox)

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to change the background colour, as well as the HTML / CSS?
We can't help you if we can't see the problem.

Comment: fiddle would be great if you can do it for your example

Comment: You can run the actual code here:

http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/848981/it/cw/cw.html

Instructions, in Chrome do:
1. click on "W+" in the right box.
2. click on a word. A menu should show up.
3. press the up arrow and look in the debugger console. It should say:

"up
p:last"

and show the element in question. Just look at the direct style of this element. (Switch to "element" view then of course.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no code was added, this is just an educated guess... well... 2 guesses:

1. The element has display: inline. Try adding display: block !important (might kill your layout, but is just a test)
2. It has somewhere else, no background with important also, with higher priority.

Comment: Thanks zozo. All wild guesses are welcome, but it already has "display: block !important". (Since I have to add all these as direct styles for a bookmarklet.)

Comment: And for your second suggestion, yes that could be a possibility. But neither the Chrome debugger or I can find it. (But maybe then Chrome screen engine. ;-) )

Comment: I am sorry if I wasted someones time :-( , but I am glad I find the problem now ;-). The 2nd case type here was the problem. I forgot that I long ago in some testing put a background color there.

And the code was unreadable since it is written by other code. I finally found it by saving the page. Because this also saves the bookmarklet I just had to throw the saved page into a good editor and do some hunting there.

Sometimes it is hard when you believe you know what you have done... 
Thanks for your thoughts too, Cerbrus, Lex Podgorny and Roloproramating. They cleared my mind a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to mark you change as !important?
You could try to write inline CSS with !important to see if change, in order to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thanks Roloprogramating, but yes, that was what I did (as I wrote ;-) ).

Comment: @Roloprogramating I'd suggest posting some complete answers (so your rep goes up and you're allowed to post comments) instead of posting rough suggestions as answers. Btw, I did the basically the same thing on my 1st/2nd post, so I'm passing the hint along :-)